# Model simplification results in non normal residuals

Tags: model-selection, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, residuals

I have a data set that includes a response variable (counts), two categorical explanatory variables, and one covariate. 
The response variable being counts, I ran a GLM with poisson distribution, and simplified the model. While the saturated model showed normal and homoskedastic residuals, as I reach the minimum adequate model, they fail normality and homoskedasticity. 
I'm a bit confused as to what the best procedure would be, and/or what the most important assumption.
If I'm just looking to assess whether the interactions have a significant effect, would it be appropriate to simply transform the data in order to do an ANCOVA?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you're running a Poisson regression, what difference does it make if the residuals are normal?

Comment: From my understanding, the standardized residuals should still be normal? By standardized, I mean: (y-fitted values)/sqrt(fitted values)

Answer (score 2):

The assumption of Poisson regression is that the response distribution is Poisson. You are estimating the parameter $\lambda$ conditional on your explanatory variables / covariates.  $y_{obs} - \lambda$ cannot be normal as it is discrete, although it will be approximately normal when $N$ and $\lambda$ are both large.  It is common (even obligatory) for Poisson data (counts) to be positively skewed when $\lambda$ is small.  In addition, for the Poisson distribution, the variance and the mean are equal (both $\lambda$), so there will always be heteroskedasticity unless $\lambda$ is constant.

If you've run a GLiM with a Poisson distribution, it sounds like you've done the right thing.  A couple of things to check for are: do you have over-dispersion, and are there more zeros than there ought to be?  But I suspect you are fine.

Comment: Thanks gung - the data is not over-dispersed, nor do I have "too many" zeros. So looks like I'm proceeding with my model simplification as I thought!

Comment: Glad to help, @Helene. If this answer provides the info you need, consider upvoting it & accepting it by clicking the check mark to the left of it.